# Symfony OnKernelRequest fail with Role

Tags: symfony, listener, roles

I'm facing an error inside de OnKernelRequest, but it is very strange:

I have 3 roles: ROLE_USER -> ROLE_ADMIN -> ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN (each Role have the preceding Role).

In my APP i have a Maintenance Mode and a Load Mode (depends on a param in the Database). I have overrriden the OnKernelRequest, to see if the APP is on Maintenance/Load Mode, and if the user is not granted with ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN, render a Maintenance View (this works perfect)

Now I want to add some conditions. The condition is that even if the user is granted with ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN, in some URL, if the APP is in Load Mode, the APP will render a Maintenance View (this doesn't work and breaks the APP). But the strange thing is that I'm using exactly the same code to redirect in each case...

I can't see the error, because the APP breaks and doesn't connect when the error condition is fired.

My security.yml code:

```
security:

    # http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/security.html#where-do-users-come-from-user-providers
    providers:
        in_memory:
            memory: 
                users:
                    guest:
                        password: ....
                        roles: 'ROLE_USER'
                    admin:
                        password: ....
                        roles: 'ROLE_ADMIN'
                    superadmin:
                        password: ....
                        roles: 'ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN'

    encoders:
        Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\User: 
            algorithm: bcrypt
            cost: 12

    firewalls:
        default:
            anonymous: ~
            form_login:
                login_path: login
                check_path: login
                use_referer: true 
                failure_path: login
                require_previous_session: false
            logout:
                path:   /logout
                target: /

    access_control:
        #- { path: ^/, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
        - { path: ^/mantenimiento, roles: ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN }
        - { path: ^/cargar, roles: ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN }
        - { path: ^/subir, roles: ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN }
        - { path: ^/productos, roles: ROLE_USER }
        - { path: ^/errores_carga, roles: ROLE_ADMIN }


    role_hierarchy:
        ROLE_ADMIN:       ROLE_USER
        ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN: ROLE_ADMIN
```

My OnKernelRequest code:

```
class MantenimientoService{

    private $em;
    private $container;

    public function __construct(ContainerInterface $container, EntityManager $entityManager)
    {
        $this->container = $container;
        $this->em = $entityManager;
    }

    public function onKernelRequest(GetResponseEvent $event)
    {
        //$event->getRequest()->get('_route') != 'app_index';

        if ($this->container->get('security.context')){

            $maintenanceMode = $this->em->getRepository("AppBundle:Configuracion")->EnMantenimiento();
            $loadMode = $this->em->getRepository("AppBundle:Configuracion")->EnCarga();

            //Si no es el superAdmin y la APP está en proceso de carga o mantenimiento, la bloqueamos
            if (!$this->container->get('security.context')->isGranted('ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN')){
                if ( $maintenanceMode || $loadMode ){
                    $vistaMantenimineto = $this->container->get('templating')->render('AppBundle:Default:mantenimiento.html.twig', array('mantenimiento' => true)); //THIS WORKS PERFECTLY
                    $event->setResponse(new Response($vistaMantenimineto)); //pintamos el template
                }
            }
            else{ //ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN
                if ($loadMode){
                    if ($event->getRequest()->get('_route') != 'subir' && $event->getRequest()->get('_route') != 'mantenimiento'){
                        /*HERE THE ERROR*/$vistaMantenimineto = $this->container->get('templating')->render('AppBundle:Default:mantenimiento.html.twig', array('mantenimiento' => true)); //THIS DOESN'T WORKS 
                        $event->setResponse(new Response($vistaMantenimineto)); //pintamos el template
                    }
                }
            }

        }

    }

}
```

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Have you checked Inside symfony log file  for some errors?

Comment: Yes, I have checked but no error is printed. The APP breaks and get a blank page with error connection.